Using shinylive to host a shiny app on GitHub
I am reaching out regarding hosting a Shiny app on GitHub Pages instead of shinyapps.io. I followed the steps outlined in the link Using Shinylive to host Shiny app on GitHub Pages | Training-modules.
The app runs smoothly in RStudio, and the interface opens without issues. However, after using Shinylive to generate the static HTML and WebR files in the docs directory, the app opens but displays a blank page. There are no errors, but no content is visible.
I used the following code to export the app to docs:
shinylive::export(appdir = "demo", destdir = "docs")

To check the app locally, I ran:
httpuv::runStaticServer("docs/", port = 8008)

could you please let me know what is the reason for this
Here is the hosted app link: Shiny App
Additionally, I've attached screenshots of the GitHub repo structure.
(Links not valid.)
https://upload://ciSYdBXRjk7CnQNO2gFyr1ZJiJB.png
and
https://upload://xi3kOBd6UC088wUAveeV4dwm0Bm.png
The demo folder contains the app.R file, and the docs folder holds the static HTML files.
Could you please help me identify why the app appears blank despite?
